# Remote Vagrant Dev Server

Tags: vagrant

I am a web developer and I am currently using Vagrant + VirtualBox to run my projects. I have a Proliant server at home that I am not using at the moment. I was thinking, is there any way I could use it instead of the VM, so I could run my projects remotely?

P.S: Can you think about any other cool use cases for this server?

Comment: "use it instead of the VM": what VM?

Comment: It really depends what you are doing with the vagrant VM. Personally I managed multiple VM and destroy / re-provision at least once a week the VM; I would not change this process over using a bare server.

Comment: @MattSchuchard the virtual machine vagrant generates using virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant is design to work with VMs or containers when using a docker provider but not bare metal server simply because the goal is to be able to build, use, destroy and rebuild environment programmatically so using a base-metal server break the main use case.

The possible course of action is to install the hypervisor on your personal server and then configure your Vagrantfile to use the remote provider instead of the local. You'll have as a direct benefit the ability to create a lot of instance since your server will most likely have more resources than your local laptop/desktop workstation.